# 'System.Linq.IQueryable(Of Integer)' cannot be converted to Integer

Tags: vb.net, linq, integer, type-conversion

I need to move data between tables.  The two tables are identical in terms of data type on each field.  However when I try to take the data from one table and place it in the other i get errors.  No doubt a very convoluted way of programming this but its the only way I know at this stage.  For each of the fields I get `Value of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable(Of Integer)' cannot be converted to Integer` or the equivalent, depending on data type.  I have been struggling with this for 3 days.  Please help!

```
    `input string`
    Dim parseRef As String = txtReferenceCode.Text

    `Convert string to integer value`
    Dim findRecord As Integer = Integer.Parse(parseRef)

    `Query the database for the row to be updated.`
    Dim modQuery = _
        (From m In db.Modules
         Join am In db.Amendments_Awaiting_Approvals On m.Module_code Equals am.Module_code
         Where am.Amendments_ID = findRecord _
         Select m)

    Dim newName = (From n In db.Amendments_Awaiting_Approvals
                   Where n.Amendments_ID = findRecord
                   Select n.Module_name_app)

    Dim newStatus = (From n In db.Amendments_Awaiting_Approvals
                  Where n.Amendments_ID = findRecord
                  Select n.Module_status_app)

    Dim newCredits = (From n In db.Amendments_Awaiting_Approvals
                  Where n.Amendments_ID = findRecord
                  Select n.Module_credits_app)

    Dim newCapacity = (From n In db.Amendments_Awaiting_Approvals
                          Where n.Amendments_ID = findRecord
                          Select n.Module_capacity_app)

    Dim newFee = (From n In db.Amendments_Awaiting_Approvals
                  Where n.Amendments_ID = findRecord
                  Select n.Fee_change)

    Dim newDesc = (From n In db.Amendments_Awaiting_Approvals
                  Where n.Amendments_ID = findRecord
                  Select n.Module_Description_app)

    ` Execute the query, and change the column values
     you want to change.  NB all fields on right had side hold the temp data to be input`
    For Each m As [Module] In modQuery
        m.Module_name = newName
        m.Module_status = newStatus
        m.Module_credits = newCredits
        m.Module_capacity = newCapacity
        m.Fee = newFee
        m.Module_Description = newDesc
```

Comment: Maybe you want to use the first row of each query, then simply add `First()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you expect only one row per query;

```
Dim newFee = (From n In db.Amendments_Awaiting_Approvals
              Where n.Amendments_ID = findRecord
              Select n.Fee_change)
```

by default this will return a "list" of Fee_change

```
Dim newFee = (From n In db.Amendments_Awaiting_Approvals
              Where n.Amendments_ID = findRecord
              Select n.Fee_change).FirstOrDefault
```

add .FirstOrDefault so it wont be a iqueryable anymore

Comment: Thanks for the response.   I did some digging in the threads and found a similar answer just after posting my question so it is all working now.  Thanks again